# having a issue with this C++ code containing number Arrays

Tags: arrays

can anyone figure out why it runs fine but then tells me theres an error afterwards, everything works but it says there is a "number" error

```css
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int number[3][3];
 int Temporary;

 std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[0][0]  = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[0][1] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[0][2] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[1][0] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[1][2] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[1][1] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[3][0] = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
 number[3][1]  = Temporary;
   std::cin >> Temporary;
  number[3][2] = Temporary;

 std::cout << number[0][0] << number[0][1] << number[0][2] << std::endl;
 std::cout << number[1][0] << number[1][1] << number[1][2] << std::endl;
 std::cout << number[3][0] << number[3][1] << number[3][2] << std::endl;

 
 system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you use a temporary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are operating out of the bound of your array. You should be using `2` for your first index instead of `3`. Which mean `number[2][1]` instead of `number[3][1]`

For a definition `int number[N][N];` the valid index range goes from 0 to N-1.

Comment: what don't you understand?

Comment: i thought number[0][0] is an valid input option, not quite sure can you fix it and post the fixed one so i can see what im doing wrong it would be much appreciated =)

Comment: I am not talking about `number[0][0]`. I am talking about `number[3][0]`, `number[3][1]`, `number[3][2]`.

Comment: cant believe i didnt realize